# Why is this promise returning an [object Promise] and not the value?

Tags: json

I thought I fully understood promises, but I'm stumped on this. I realize I should use async/await, but for this example I specifically want to only use .then().

When I do this:

```
const theJson = fetch(
  `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/28963/quotes.json`
)
    .then( quoteTypeResponse => quoteTypeResponse.json() )
    .then( data => {
        console.log(data)
        return data
    });
```

the `console.log(data)` in the last function prints the JSON as expected, but when I try to `console.log(theJson)`, the returned value, it prints [object Promise].. Why is this?

I was able to get the data outside of the function using react's useState/useEffect but not with just a vanilla global variable. I'm not trying to solve anything, but just want to understand why this does not work.

```
export default function App() {
  let globalVar;
  const [theQuote, setTheQuote] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/28963/quotes.json`)
      .then(quoteTypeResponse => quoteTypeResponse.json())
      .then(quoteType =>
        fetch(
          'https://programming-quotes-api.herokuapp.com/quotes/' +
            quoteType.type
        )
      )
      .then(quoteResponse => {
        return quoteResponse.json();
      })
      .then(quote => {
        setTheQuote({ quote: quote.en, author: quote.author });
        globalVar = quote.author;
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <div id="app">
      <h1>{theQuote.quote}</h1> // renders
      <h2>{theQuote.author}</h2> // renders
      <h3>globalVar: {globalVar}</h3> // undefined
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: the then function returns a promise. you'd have to await it if you want the actual result

Comment: I'm fine with using async and await, but I wanted to specifically solve this without using async/await. Is that not possible? How was it done before async/await was released?

Comment: async/await just transpiles into thens. So before async/await, you would put a then on the promise and console.log from inside of the function (basically exactly what you're doing with console.log(data))

Comment: But what if I want to store the value in an variable and not merely console.log it?

Comment: then you would do all that storing inside of the then function. this is why await was invented. it makes the code look nicer. any reason why you don't just want to use await

Comment: I have been using async/await which is why I think I'm mixing up the two styles. I was just trying to remember how I dealt with promises before async/await. So the only way to  to wrap all everything inside the promise? That doesn't seem right. What if I wanted to use the returned value somewhere else? I tried setting a global variable and assigning it while inside the then, but that doesn't even work. MDN docs say: If a handler function returns a value, the promise returned by then gets resolved with the returned value as its value.

Comment: it may not seem right, but that's how you would have to do it. you can read up on that [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/async-await-vs-promises-4fe98d11038f). If you want to use the returned value, then yes the then function that gets passed that value would have to contain all the code that needs to use it. again, this is why `await` was invented.  makes it much easier. what didn't work in your case? I'm guessing you assigned the global, but then logged it before the promise resolved. it's not recommended to do that

Comment: @pushkin I'm starting to realize why people were so enthusiastic about async/await. What didn't work was declaring a global variable and then trying to assign it within the .then() block. I was able to get the data outside of the function using react's useState/useEffect but not with just a vanilla global variable. I'll post my code in an edit.

Comment: yeah that doesn't work because you're returning before the async stuff that sets globalVar has run. instead of setting globalVar in your last then, you should return the <div> stuff and have the function should return a promise if it makes sense. "await" will make this easier to handle

Comment: Thanks. That was a good link you sent. I'm going to close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@pushkin left a good link explaining the differences between async/await and using .then(), but basically, the value returned by the then() is only available within that block.

Promises cheat sheet: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/async-await-vs-promises-4fe98d11038f

```
fetch(`https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/28963/quotes.json`)
  .then(quoteTypeResponse => quoteTypeResponse.json())
  .then(quoteType =>
    fetch(
      'https://programming-quotes-api.herokuapp.com/quotes/' + quoteType.type
    )
  )
  .then(quoteResponse => {
    return quoteResponse.json();
  })
  .then(quote => {
    console.log(`q:${util.inspect(quote)}`);
    document.getElementById('app').innerHTML = quote.en;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your second `.then()` is **inside** the first `then()`, so `theJson` is a `Promise<T>`. The nice thing about `Promise<T>` is that you can move an inner `.then()` call up a level and it will still work:

Change it from this:

```
const theJson = fetch(
  `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/28963/quotes.json`
)
    .then( quoteTypeResponse => quoteTypeResponse.json().then( data => {
        console.log(data)
        return data
    } )
);
```

To this:

```
const theJson = fetch(
  `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/28963/quotes.json`
)
    .then( quoteTypeResponse => quoteTypeResponse.json() )
    .then( data => {
        console.log(data)
        return data
    });
```

But ideally, use `async function` so you can have this *considerably* simpler code instead:

```
const resp = await fetch( `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/28963/quotes.json` );
const data = await resp.json();
console.log( data );
```

Comment: `theJson` is still not printing the value with your solution. I realize I should use async/await, but I specifically was trying to do it without for this example.